# How to create custom module with inhertit the Customer registration fields to my module page - Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, customer, registration

**i want to copy the customer registration fields to my custom module page**

can i copy

`vendor/module/customer`

to my module

or else 
how i can inherit to my page

Note:
All the attributes are value stored customer account